# Stream closed after async

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, stream, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a ASP.NET core application that need to send a stream(the stream is posted by client) to Microsoft Cognitive Service to get the ID. And then send the same stream to azure blob for backup, the file name should be the ID received from Cognitive Service.

But it seems like the MemoryStream ms closed after used by faceServiceClient : an error accrued at the second "ms.Position = 0" statement saying "Cannot access a closed stream".

```
public static async Task CreatPerson(string _key, HttpRequest _req)
{
    var faceServiceClient = new FaceServiceClient(_key);
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        _req.Body.CopyTo(ms);
        ms.Position = 0;
        var facesTask = faceServiceClient.AddFaceToFaceListAsync("himlens", ms);
        //init azure blob
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(AZURE_STORE_CONN_STR);
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("xxx");
        var faces = await facesTask;
        var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(faces.PersistedFaceId.ToString());

        ms.Position = 0;//Error Here
        await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(ms);
    }
}
```

I'm confused about it, can anybody help me solve this problem?

Thanks！

Comment: Does `AddFaceToFaceListAsync` close the stream perhaps? Anyway, if you intend to pass the stream's data to multiple methods, extract the buffer and pass it to the methods instead of trying to change the stream's position. Finally, you shouldn't use `.Wait()` or `.Result` with tasks. The last line should be `await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(ms);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ms.Position = 0;//Error Here

To easily fix it, you could create a new instance of MemoryStream and copy the value from ms. Then you could upload it to your blob storage. Code below is for your reference.

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    _req.Body.CopyTo(ms);
    ms.Position = 0;
    //new code which I added 
    MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream();
    ms.CopyTo(ms2);
    ms.Position = 0;

    var facesTask = faceServiceClient.AddFaceToFaceListAsync("himlens", ms);
    //init azure blob
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(AZURE_STORE_CONN_STR);
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("xxx");
    var faces = await facesTask;
    var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(faces.PersistedFaceId.ToString());
    //Code which I modified
    ms2.Position = 0;
    await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(ms2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me, but there are still a problem which is when

Comment: What is the new problem? Did you upload ms2 to azure blob storage? Since ms2 and ms are different stream. Any changes affect ms will not related to ms2.

Comment: I'm pretty sorry that I missent that commit when I'm trying to solve that problem. The problem is ms2 will not be able to flush unless I kill the program, then I add a "ms2.Flush();", It functions pretty good. Thanks a lot for helping me!